# modalPopupExtender when shown from code-behind doesnt apply the transparency to the background

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

While wanting modalPopupExtender to show from code-behind, everything works well except

- the opacity and alpha(filter) properties of the CSS are not applied meaning i get a modal popup with the color i set in my BackgroundCSSClass and hence cannot see my original controls in the background.

anyone facing this weird behavior and have a solution for this?

B.t.w, Everything works well when the TargetControlID is not hidden.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  And could you show the ASPX markup for the `ModalPopupExtender`?

Answer (score 0):

I battled this same issue for most of the day today. I have 3 pages with this identical code in them.  two of the pages worked as expected, with transparent background, one did not. In that one, the background was always 100% opaque.

Finally,  I realised i had accidentally deleted the `< !DOCTYPE html >` line in that page.  Adding that one line back into the page fixed the problem instantly.  Simple. and a little unexpected. HTH

Comment: I am using Master Pages, and i have the `< !DOCTYPE html>` line there.